# How to update the Quartz Trigger State manually to COMPLETED using SQL scripts

Tags: quartz.net

By mistake I have created a multiple rows in the Quartz table instead of updating the existing entry, I have created a new row and now need to mark the trigger state to `COMPLETED`

So if I run below query like

```sql
UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = 'COMPLETED' WHERE QUARTZ_ID='96b80f9e-6ce0-474d-89e1-3fa8c48c61c5'
```

Do I have to update other tables also? I am using Quartz version 3.0.7

[image: Database viewer]